# Options for overnight layover in Delhi

Tags: layovers, hotels

I'm travelling to Kathmandu and most of my flight options include an overnight layover in Delhi, with an early morning flight out to Nepal.

What are my options for finding somewhere to sleep? It's only 8 hours, so going into Delhi probably isn't practical.

Comment: http://www.newdelhiairport.in/sleeping-pods-airport.aspx  or use the Holiday Inn hotel at terminal 3. If you are transferring from International to domestic contact the hotel and they will fetch you and direct you to the hotel. Else you will need to get out of the airport and change terminals which is a bit taxing.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to this [link](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/asia/delhi.htm) for options for sleeping in New Delhi airport.

> **Where to Sleep**
>
> - T3’s Airside has plenty of options to stretch out if you can grab a    spot. Look for the couches in the main shopping area. There’s plenty of seats with and without armrests, and carpet in most spots.
> - It never totally quiets down with so many overnight flights, so bring    those earplugs and eye masks.
> - A few travellers report airport staff asking them to move from the    carpeted floor.
> - For uninterrupted sleep, there is a transit hotel and sleeping pods    inside the airport and several hotels are located nearby. See Airport 
>     Hotels in the airport guide below.

Link to [Airport Hotels](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/asia/delhi.htm#airportHotel)